# How do you pass a function through a component that has a spread operator?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Sorry, beginner at react here. I am having some difficulty trying to pass info to a parent component via prop drill in order to set the values into a context API so I can pass the info to another component.

I have an array called `foodItem` that was passed down from App.js to the component below with `onGetFood` function. I created another intermediary testing function called `getFoodItemInfo` to pass onto the next component `ChildFoodItem`.

```
//FoodList.jsx

function FoodItem ({foodItem}, {onGetFood}) {

    function getFoodItemInfo (food) {
        onGetFood();
        console.log("FOOOD");
    }

    return (
         <ChildFoodItem {...foodItem} **getFood={getFoodItemInfo}**/>
    );
}

//ChildFoodItem.jsx

    function ChildFoodItem (food, {getFood}) {
        
            getFood();
        
            return (
            <p className="flex-container">
                {/* First row - Macros */}
                <p className='task flex-child'>
                    <Button onClick={(e) => getFood()} style={{font: "bold"}} variant="link">{food.description} </Button>
                </p>
            </p>
            )
        }
```

However, when I tried to pass `getFood` to the `ChildFoodItem`, I'm getting that the function is undefined? Is there a rule that you can't prop drill a function if you use a spread operator?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to destructure the prop parameter, which is the first parameter that the component receives. By specifying multiple parameters (`food, {getFood}`), the props end up in `food`, and any other parameter will be undefined. The correct syntax would be:

```
function ChildFoodItem ({ getFood, ...food })
```

This would get the `getFood` function out of the props, and place the rest of them in the `food` variable.

For more details on that, see the "Rest in Object Destructuring" section on the ["Destructuring assignment" documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

React components receive only a single argument, the `props` object. With `function ChildFoodItem (food, {getFood})` you are attempting to destructure `getFood` from an undefined argument. The props object you named `food`.

## Solution

Given the props are passed as:

```
<ChildFoodItem {...foodItem} getFood={getFoodItemInfo} />
```

Then `getFood` can be explicitly destructured while the rest of the `food` props are spread into a variable named `food` (*or any other valid identifier*).

```
function ChildFoodItem ({ getFood, ...food }) {

  getFood();

  return (
    <p className="flex-container">
      {/* First row - Macros */}
      <p className='task flex-child'>
        <Button onClick={(e) => getFood()} style={{font: "bold"}} variant="link">{food.description} </Button>
      </p>
    </p>
  )
}
```